# How can I send UDP messages to a client that is behind LAN network?

Tags: network-programming, udp, client-server, lan, udpclient

I'm building a server that use UDP protocol to send and receive UDP message to and from clients.
Clients continuously "throw" UDP message to server without server responding anything, when the server "think" that it had received enough UDP messages from certain client, it will send a signal message (UDP message) back to THE client (this time, client acts as an server) to prevent it from sending any more messages.
The problem here is that: The server can receive UDP messages from clients. But clients (which is behind LAN network) can't receive UDP messages from server.
How can I send UDP messages to a client that is behind LAN network?

Comment: How long does it take for the server to send a UDP datagram to the client. Is it immediately after having received the last UDP message? (the one that surpasses the limit)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the router, Some would set a route for some time when the datagram is 1st send by the LAN member to the server, the router might take note as the udp packet is part of a 'UDP Session' and route it accordingly.
The other way I'd try is utilizing [UPnP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13285/Using-UPnP-for-Programmatic-Port-Forwardings-and-N) to forward the correct port (I.E. the port that the client machine is using) to the LAN member.